# Unable to send body,subject in mail from camel spring SMTP component

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm writing one basic camel application using camel-spring.I'm able to send email but Im not able to send body and subject in it.I have tried several ways but only thing im getting in mail body is file contents.Please provide your inputs if you have any idea.

```
    <route id="notification">
        <from uri="file:///home?noop=true" />
        <camel:choice>
            <camel:when>
                <camel:simple>
                ${file:name} contains '{{data}}'
                </camel:simple>

                <camel:setHeader headerName="from">
                    <simple>nikhil@from.com</simple>
                </camel:setHeader>

                <setHeader headerName="subject">
                    <constant>Hello subject</constant>
                </setHeader>

                <setHeader headerName="contentType">
                    <constant>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</constant>
                </setHeader>

                <camel:setHeader headerName="body">
                    <constant>Test body</constant>
                </camel:setHeader>

                <camel:setBody>
                    <constant>Test camel set body</constant>
                </camel:setBody>

                <setBody>
                    <constant>Test  set body</constant>
                </setBody>

                <camel:setOutHeader headerName="subject">
                    <simple>subject from outheader</simple>
                </camel:setOutHeader>
                <setHeader headerName="subject">
                    <constant>Status of check report extractor</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <camel:to uri="smtps://smtp.server.com:465?username=user@gmail.com&amp;password=pass&amp;to=receiver@yahoo.com&amp;subject=${subject}"></camel:to>
            </camel:when>
        </camel:choice>
</route>
```

I have added all combinations that I have tried,but they are not workingThanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please, give a try to this route.

```
<route id="notification">
    <from uri="file:///home?noop=true" />
        <setHeader headerName="from">
            <constant>nikhil@from.com</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="subject">
            <constant>Hello subject</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="contentType">
            <constant>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setBody>
             <constant>Test camel set body</constant>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="smtps://smtp.server.com:465?username=user@gmail.com&amp;password=pass&amp;to=receiver@yahoo.com&amp;from=${header.from}&amp;subject=${header.subject}&amp;contentType=${header.contentType}"/>
</route>
```

Then we can check the "when/simple" condition.

Note that all the stored headers in the route may be retrieved with ${header.X}.

Comment: Thanks.I have resolved that issue by placing all set headers above choice tag and after from tag.But I didn't understand why is it not working if I place set headers in choice tag.Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked if your "simple" tag complies the condition? I like to insert "log" tags in the route to check if the execution is passing all the route steps. By the way, you should use the "choice" tag when you have multiple "when" tags to choose or with "when/otherwise" combination but if there is only one "when" tag you can omit the "choice" one.

Comment: Thanks.I have multiple conditions,but here I posted just one to avoid lengthy code.I'll try with simple tag.